# C adding up integers stored from a loop

Tags: c, variables, syntax, while-loop, initialization

I want my program to ask the user for numbers, afterwards displaying how many entries were even and odd, then displaying the total of all the even entries and the total of all the odd entries.

I've got it all except the total part.

How do I reference correctly the entries from my `oddcount++` and `evencount++` ?
I was thinking maybe an array but that may be over-complicating things. For loop dealing with the total?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int evencount = 0, oddcount = 0, i = 0;
int eventotal, oddtotal;



int main () {


int number;
char name[256];



printf("Enter your name \n");
scanf("%s", &name);

printf("Enter numbers within 1-100 \n");
printf("Enter 0 to quit\n");

while (number != 0) {
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number%2 == 1) {
        oddcount++;
    }
    else {
        evencount++;

    }

};



printf("%s,the numbers you have entered are broken down as follows: \n", name);


    printf("%d odd entries \n", oddcount);
    printf("%d even entries\n", evencount);

//printf("You entered even numbers with a total value of %d \n", eventotal );
//printf("You entered odd numbers with a total value of %d \n", oddtotal);



return 0;

}
```

Comment: `number` is not inited. Compile your code with `-Wall` option and see what happen...

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in your program as you use the variable `number` uninitialized. Because it's not initialized its value will be *indeterminate*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is keep integers for even and odd sum and add them on the fly when the user enters the numbers.

And initialize the variable `number` since the first comparison in the `while` loop is with an uninitialized variable, thats [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You loop should look something like this

```
number = 1;
while (number != 0)
{
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number%2 == 1)
    {
        oddcount++;
        oddtotal += number;
    }
    else 
    {
        evencount++;
        eventotal += number
    }
}

printf("sum of even number = %d\n", eventotal);
printf("sum of odd number = %d\n", oddtotal);
```

---

Since array name is the base address of that array, you do not need `&` for `scanf()`

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

---

**NOTE:**

1)
Use the standard definition of `main()`

```
int main(void) //if no command line arguments.
```

2) Global variables default initialization value is `0`. So you don't need to initialize them like you did here.

```
int evencount = 0, oddcount = 0, i = 0;
```

Comment: I didn't know about the initializing part, thanks for that and for the other tidbits! Just wondering is there anyway to take some of this and make a user-defined function outside of int(main), like leaving the entry selection in int(main) and having the if/else outside?

Comment: @Jclee, definitely. Read about functions and how they work. And how you can send and receive variables and all.

Answer (score 2):

Use two variables:

```
int evensum = 0, oddsum = 0;

if (number%2 == 1) {
    oddcount++;
    oddsum += number;
}
else {
    evencount++;
    evensum += number;

}
```

Or an array with two entires:

```
// The sum of the even numbers go in sum[0], and the sum of the odd numbers
// go in sum[1]
int sum[] = {0, 0};

if (number%2 == 1) {
    oddcount++;
}
else {
    evencount++;

}
sum[number&1] += number;
```

Answer (score 2):

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int evencount = 0, oddcount = 0;
    unsigned int eventotal = 0, oddtotal = 0;

    unsigned int number;
    char name[256];

    printf( "Enter your name: " );
    scanf( "%255s", name );

    printf( "Enter numbers within 1-100 \n" );
    printf( "Enter 0 to quit\n" );

    while ( scanf( "%u", &number ) == 1 && number != 0 ) 
    {
        if ( number % 2 == 1 ) 
        {
            oddcount++;
            oddtotal += number;
        }
        else 
        {
            evencount++;
            eventotal += number;
        }
    }

    printf( "%s,the numbers you have entered are broken down as follows: \n", name);

    printf( "%u odd entries \n", oddcount );
    printf( "%u even entries\n", evencount );

    printf( "You entered even numbers with a total value of %u\n", eventotal );
    printf( "You entered odd numbers with a total value of %u \n", oddtotal );

    return 0;
}
```

Or the program could be written using arrays instead of separate variables. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    enum { Even = 0, Odd = 1 };

    unsigned int counts[2] = { 0, 0 };
    unsigned int totals[2] = { 0, 0 };

    unsigned int number;
    char name[256];

    printf( "Enter your name: " );
    scanf( "%255s", name );

    printf( "Enter numbers within 1-100 \n" );
    printf( "Enter 0 to quit\n" );

    while ( scanf( "%u", &number ) == 1 && number != 0 ) 
    {
        ++counts[number % 2];
        totals[number % 2] += number;
    }

    printf( "%s,the numbers you have entered are broken down as follows: \n", name);

    printf( "%u odd entries \n", counts[Odd] );
    printf( "%u even entries\n", counts[Even] );

    printf( "You entered even numbers with a total value of %u\n", totals[Even] );
    printf( "You entered odd numbers with a total value of %u \n", totals[Odd] );

    return 0;
}
```

If your compiler supports C99 then you could initialize the arrays the following way for readability

```
unsigned int counts[2] = { [Even] = 0, [Odd] = 0 };
unsigned int totals[2] = { [Even] = 0, [Odd] = 0 };
```

As for your while loop

```
while (number != 0) {
    scanf("%d", &number);
    if (number%2 == 1) {
        oddcount++;
    }
    else {
        evencount++;

    }
};
^^^
```

then for starters there is no need to place an empty statement after it. 
Variable `number` was not initialized and has indeterminate value.
Function `scanf` can issue an error. In this case variable number will not contain a new value. However it is checked in the loop. As result the loop can be infinite.
And at last you have to include increments of variables `oddtotal` and `eventotal` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
int number;
```

should be

```
int number=1;
```

Otherwise is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Second thing

```
scanf("%s", &name);
```

have to be

```
scanf("%s", name);
```

If you try to compile your code with -Wall option it will warn you about this last point:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:467:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[256]’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%s", &name);
  ^
```

Last thing your loop must avoid to count 0 as a even number:

```
while (number != 0)
{
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if (number)
    {
        if (number%2 == 1)
        {
            oddcount++;
        }
        else
        {
            evencount++;
        }
    }
}
```